# How can I convert a row of years that also contains NaNs in integers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is the head of my dataframe (immigration):

```
    nan 1850.0  1851.0  1852.0  1853.0  1854.0  1855.0  1856.0  1857.0  1858.0  ... 2008.0  2009.0  2010.0  2011.0  2012.0  2013.0  2014.0  2015.0  2016.0  2017.0
0   NaN 1850.000000 1851.000000 1852.000000 1853.000000 1854.000000 1855.000000 1856.000000 1857.000000 1858.000000 ... 2008.000000 2009.000000 2010.000000 2011.000000 2012.000000 2013.000000 2014.000000 2015.000000 2016.000000 2017.000000
1   California  0.235450    0.282475    0.311489    0.331177    0.345413    0.356185    0.364622    0.371407    0.376984    ... 0.268349    0.269110    0.271770    0.270484    0.270779    0.268994    0.270921    0.273046    0.272042    0.269457
2   New York    0.211768    0.217419    0.222798    0.227924    0.232815    0.237486    0.241952    0.246226    0.250320    ... 0.212731    0.213811    0.221615    0.221817    0.226076    0.223056    0.226143    0.228841    0.229732    0.228741
3   New Jersey  0.122454    0.130429    0.137851    0.144774    0.151249    0.157317    0.163015    0.168377    0.173430    ... 0.199191    0.202058    0.209573    0.214619    0.212452    0.216395    0.219366    0.220733    0.225400    0.228197
```

What I would like to do is:
1) Get rid of that "nan" at the beginning, and replace it with the word "Country"
2) I would like to get rid of the decimal points in the numbers in the header since those are years

I tried:

```
immigration.columns = pd.to_numeric(immigration.iloc[0], downcast='integer', errors='coerce')
```

Also:

```
immigration.iloc[0].astype(int)
```

None of those worked.

Comment: Can you post your DataFrame as text, not as an image

Comment: Also, I would recommend fixing this issue when you read the Data in, as opposed to trying to fix it afterwards.  This looks like a case of input that needs to be cleaned

Comment: Just shared the DataFrame as text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Disclaimer***
I personally would advise fixing this data at the source, so that once you read it into a DataFrame, you don't have to deal with this type of data cleaning.  If that is not an option, you can use this approach.

---

First, replace the `NaN` with your `Country` header:

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0].fillna('Country').astype(str).values
```

```
      Country       1850.0       1851.0       1852.0       1853.0       1854.0       1855.0
0         NaN  1850.000000  1851.000000  1852.000000  1853.000000  1854.000000  1855.000000
1  California     0.235450     0.282475     0.311489     0.331177     0.345413     0.356185
2    New York     0.211768     0.217419     0.222798     0.227924     0.232815     0.237486
3  New Jersey     0.122454     0.130429     0.137851     0.144774     0.151249     0.157317
```

Now use a regular expression to rename your columns, and slice your DataFrame:

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub(r'\.\d+', '', x)).iloc[1:]
```

```
      Country      1850      1851      1852      1853      1854      1855
1  California  0.235450  0.282475  0.311489  0.331177  0.345413  0.356185
2    New York  0.211768  0.217419  0.222798  0.227924  0.232815  0.237486
3  New Jersey  0.122454  0.130429  0.137851  0.144774  0.151249  0.157317
```